# Unix CRON JOB to send PHP Mail every minute

Tags: php, shell, unix, cron

I have a php mailer script **mailer.php** under **public_html** directory. Which works fine when I directly access it through **domain.com/mailer.php**

PHP Mailer Script

```
<?php
$from = "mail@gmail.com"; // sender
    $subject = "Subject";
    $message = "Message of mail";
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    mail("mail@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
?>
```

But I want to execute this script every minute using unix shell cron job

I am using Putty.exe Shell Terminal (For Windows)

I have saved following cron code in **public_html/mailer.txt**

```
* * * * * /home/user/public_html/mailer.php
```

Changed Shell Terminal Directory to **/public_html** and running following command

```
crontab mailer.txt
```

Now I am expecting to get mails in my above defined Email ID every minute but Its not working.
Please Help me to find out where am I doing wrong.

Comment: You should test like that: `php /home/user/public_html/mailer.php`

Comment: @gibberish As i mentioned above script is working fine when I am directly running the php file.

Comment: @hsaka you are testing through the browser, the proper way to test CLI is to use php command

Comment: @meda I modified **mailer.txt** to `* * * * * php /home/user/public_html/mailer.php` and its working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
* * * * * /home/user/public_html/mailer.php
```

to

```
* * * * * php /home/user/public_html/mailer.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file is simply not executable. You probably want to call `php` instead:

```
* * * * * php /home/user/public_html/mailer.php
```

... or to be on the safe side:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/mailer.php
```

... where `/usr/bin/php` should be replaced with the actual path to your php binary.

Additionally, you can convert the file itself into a Linux script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$from = "mail@gmail.com"; // sender
    $subject = "Subject";
    $message = "Message of mail";
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    mail("mail@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
?>
```

... and tell Linux that it is an executable file. E.g., if the file is saved as `/home/user/bin/mailer` (there's no need to save it into Apache document root):

```
chmod +x /home/user/bin/mailer
```

Now it's possible to schedule the file itself:

```
* * * * * /home/user/bin/mailer
```

You can find further details in the [Executing PHP files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) section of the manual.

Answer (score 0):

In your cron file, you need to be executing:

```
/usr/bin/wget localhost/mailer.php
```

This should execute the PHP code you have inside your file. However, I would recommend setting up a .htaccess file so that localhost is the only person that can execute that PHP file.

Good luck!

Comment: Using HTTP to execute local scripts is a extended practice but it's really awful.

Comment: Why is it really awful, @Alvado?

Comment: It means exposing your local programs to the entire world and adding two unnecessary steps (wget and Apache) for no reason. It's the equivalent of picking up the phone to talk to someone you've having lunch with.

Comment: .htaccess would prevent your local programs from being exposed to the entire world, but I see what you're saying about adding two unnecessary steps.